# phpinfo.php while with apache 2.4 is just returning the code

Tags: apache, php, mod-php

I am trying to configure PHP with apache 2.4 and everytime I run the localhost/phpinfo.php, it shows me the code.

browser used: chrome
changes in apache server httpd conf file: 
LoadModule php7_module "C:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "c:/php"

phpinfo file:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

tried almost all the answers but everytime it is showing me this file content only when running localhost/phpinfo.php

Note: localhost is running fine.

Comment: make sure that you had restarted you apache after any modification

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked and answered many times. There are many potential answers depending on where you got Apache and PHP from.

If you can't troubleshoot, just download XAMPP: https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

For troubleshooting see: [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)